# Git push to master which is ahead by one commit

Tags: git, github

I am having two branches (branch-local and master, which is remote). I have made my changes in 'branch-local'. When I tried to push a commit, someone else pushed into remote master and is hence one commit ahead.
Following are some commands and outputs

```
git branch
* branch-local
master

git log -3 --oneline
d41d364 (HEAD -> branch-local) 401 Error fix
78479c5 Changes in index.jsp
b402271 adding alert mechanism

git checkout master
20dae35 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Correcting the json file
78479c5 Changes in index.jsp
b402271 adding alert mechanism
```

I want my commit on top of branch-local to be on top of mater remote. I want it to look like:

```
git log -3 --oneline
d41d364 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) 401 Error fix
20dae35 Correcting the json file
78479c5 Changes in index.jsp
```

I am very new to Git and I do not want to merge my branches as it has done multiple times in past and won't be a best practice.

Comment: Have you tried rebasing your branch on master? Then the merge is a trivial fast-forward.

Comment: First you do `git pull --rebase`

Comment: First pull the latest  remote changes to your current working repository, i.e.,  ```git pull origin master```    so that ```20dae35``` will be present in your working repository, make sure you are in master branch by running ```git branch``` and run ```git log``` now you able to see ```20dae35```   now run ```git merge branch-local``` your branch-local changes will be merged to master branch, again run ```git log```  to check your changes in master branch and push to remote.

Comment: 1, ```git pull origin master```                                                                           2, ```git branch``` (branch should be in master)                             3, ```git merge branch-local```